# RecyclerView Scroll Not Working Inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have checked a lot of answers, but none of the solutions work for me!

The layout I have is:

```
<NestedScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
     <OtherLayouts>
     <LinearLayout>
       <RecyclerView>
       <OtherLayouts>
     </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

My problem is that I have to scroll the recyclerView to a particular position initially itself.
I have tried:
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)

the height for my recyclerView is already set to wrap_content

Happy to provide any other details. Pls help if you know the solution!

Answer (score 0):

are you using this line in your RecyclerView

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

will manage the rest of things.